# Discord py not recognizing command

Tags: python, discord

client.event works fine, connection and messages are registered. But cannot get discord to recognize command when I type i.e. '.ping'
python 3.7 on anaconda distribution

```
    import os
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv('.env.txt')
    TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')


    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        print(f'{client.user} has sent a message')

    @client.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
        print('test')
        await ctx.send('test') 

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright, you need to understand that overridng the default on_message forbids any extra commands from running.

An easy fix for this, is to add a `client.process_commands(message)` to the end of the on_message event. 
So in your case:

````
    import discord
    from discord.ext import commands
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv('.env.txt')
    TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')


    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        print(f'{client.user} has sent a message')
        client.process_commands(message)

    @client.command()
    async def ping(ctx):
        print('test')
        await ctx.send('test') 

    client.run(TOKEN)```
````